# Illstrator CS5: Wide selection border

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've noticed than when I select more than one object, then click on one of the selected object a wide selection border is set on the clicked item. 
eg:

[image]

What does it mean? What are the implications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're selecting a reference object. If you were to use the "align right / left / top / bottom" it would align everything in relation to the reference object. So if you had a bunch of squares and you wanted them all to be the aligned at the top of a particular one (instead of averaged across the various heights) you'd select that particular box as the reference object, click "align top", and the tops of all of the boxes would be aligned with the top of the reference box.

My favorite use of this is to select two objects, make one the reference object by clicking on it again, and use the "Set object spacing" with "0" as the value. The two objects will then be right next to each other with no space in between and no overlap.

Comment: Oh, nice! I didn't get the last part of your answer though. Where's  the _set object spacing_ feature?

Comment: In the "Align" panel; it's actually labeled "Distribute Spacing". It won't work unless you set a reference object first.

Comment: Ok, ok, I didn't even know there was an align panel (I always use the toolbar). Thanks a lot.